# How to configure Yarn Berry, Eslint with GlobalCache in VsCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

Is there a way to install EsLint with Yarn Berry with yarn option `enableGlobalCache: true` in VsCode ?

I installed the ESLint (dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) extension and all dependencies :

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": ">=7.12.0 <8.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": ">=7.10.4 <8.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": ">=7.8.3 <8.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": ">=7.12.0 <8.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": ">=7.12.0 <8.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": ">=7.10.4 <8.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": ">=7.12.0 <8.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": ">=10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": ">=8.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.12.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "file-loader": ">=6.1.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": ">=4.1.0",
    "webpack": ">=5.2.0",
    "webpack-cli": ">=4.1.0"
  }
```

If I do a `yarn eslint --init` and let npm install all node_modules, eslint works but `yarn up` will erase node_modules and I have to reinstall the modules.

If I don't install the modules :

```
    Error: An error occurred while generating your JavaScript config file. A config file was still generated, but the config file itself may not follow your linting rules.
Error: Cannot read config file: C:\FrontApplication\Abc\Main\Source\myProject\.yarn\$$virtual\eslint-config-airbnb-virtual-094ee35fd8\6\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Yarn\Berry\cache\eslint-config-airbnb-npm-18.2.0-898fc49dc6-6.zip\node_modules\eslint-config-airbnb\index.js
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Projets\Abc\Main\Source\myProject\.yarn\$$virtual\eslint-config-airbnb-virtual-094ee35fd8\6\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Yarn\Berry\cache\eslint-config-airbnb-npm-18.2.0-898fc49dc6-6.zip\node_modules\eslint-config-airbnb\index.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Yarn\Berry\cache\@eslint-eslintrc-npm-0.2.1-88318143fb-6.zip\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\noop.js
Require stack:
- C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Yarn\Berry\cache\@eslint-eslintrc-npm-0.2.1-88318143fb-6.zip\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\noop.js
Referenced from: BaseConfig
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.external_module_.Module._resolveFilename (C:\FrontApplication\Abc\Main\Source\myProject\.pnp.js:10974:54)
    at resolveFileName (C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Yarn\Berry\cache\resolve-from-npm-4.0.0-f758ec21bf-6.zip\node_modules\resolve-from\index.js:29:39)
    at resolveFrom (C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Yarn\Berry\cache\resolve-from-npm-4.0.0-f758ec21bf-6.zip\node_modules\resolve-from\index.js:43:9)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Yarn\Berry\cache\resolve-from-npm-4.0.0-f758ec21bf-6.zip\node_modules\resolve-from\index.js:46:41)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Yarn\Berry\cache\import-fresh-npm-3.2.1-b4f6711244-6.zip\node_modules\import-fresh\index.js:13:19)
    at loadJSConfigFile (C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Yarn\Berry\cache\@eslint-eslintrc-npm-0.2.1-88318143fb-6.zip\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\config-array-factory.js:225:16)
    at loAbconfigFile (C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Yarn\Berry\cache\@eslint-eslintrc-npm-0.2.1-88318143fb-6.zip\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\config-array-factory.js:308:20)
    at ConfigArrayFactory._loAbconfigData (C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Yarn\Berry\cache\@eslint-eslintrc-npm-0.2.1-88318143fb-6.zip\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\config-array-factory.js:608:42)
    at ConfigArrayFactory._loadExtendedShareableConfig (C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Yarn\Berry\cache\@eslint-eslintrc-npm-0.2.1-88318143fb-6.zip\node_modules\@eslint\eslintrc\lib\config-array-factory.js:883:21)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not install packages individually
use : `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode`

https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks

Global cache works fine afterwards